# Windows environement variables. How do I change the name that I must type at command prompt to run a path target

Tags: windows, path

*Duplicate of https://superuser.com/q/1066027/96662*

Okay, I am using Windows 10 Pro.

I have two programs with the same exact named .exe file that I want to target in my path variable in system variables.

Example:
Program 1's path: C:\somefolder\anotherfolder\prog.exe
Program 2's path: C:\evenmorefolders\prog.exe

Now, as you can see, I can't run both just by putting their filepaths in the path variable because then it will only use the first one listed when I type prog in the command prompt.

I want to set one of these programs to be opened with a name other than prog. I want to be able to type say free in order to use the prog.exe of program 2.

How do I set the environment variables to do that.

EDIT:
For anyone else requiring an answer, I got an answer that worked for me here:
https://superuser.com/questions/1066027/windows-environement-variables-how-do-i-change-the-name-that-i-must-type-at-com

Comment: This is a question better suited for the SuperUser forum: http://superuser.com

Comment: If you got an answer over at SuperUser, you should probably delete the question here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is essentially asking [How do I inflate a bicycle tire with a potato?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070607-00/?p=26523/)